# shorthand typedef pointer to a constant struct

Tags: c, coding-style, standards

Declaring a struct with typedef

```
typedef struct some_struct {
int someValue;
} *pSomeStruct;
```

and then passing it as a parameter to some function with const declaration, implying 'const some_struct * var'

```
void someFunction1( const pSomeStruct var )
```

turns out to become

```
some_struct * const var
```

This is also stated in Section 6.7.5.1 of the ISO C standard which states that 'const' in this case applies to the pointer and not to the data to which it points.

So the question is - is there a way to declare a pointer to a const struct in a shorthanded notation with typedef, or there must always be a special separate declaration for it:

```
typedef const struct some_struct *pcSomeStruct;
void someFunction2( pcSomeStruct var )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, do not typedef pointers :)

```
typedef struct some_struct {} some_struct;

void some_function1(some_struct *var);
void some_function2(const some_struct *var);
void some_function3(some_struct *const var);
void some_function4(const some_struct *const var);
```

---

Or, don't typedef at all :D

```
struct some_struct {};

void some_function1(struct some_struct *var);
void some_function2(const struct some_struct *var);
void some_function3(struct some_struct *const var);
void some_function4(const struct some_struct *const var);
```

Comment: That's why I want it shorthanded :) The function parameters are clogged with words though they are perfectly explicit

Comment: shorthand is not necessarily a good thing: is `cpu` short for Critical Patch Update or something else? I like explicit..ness

Comment: @user757808 - I much prefer to see the `const` keyword in a pointer than to see `user_defined_const_pointer_typedef` and have to figure out which naming convention the API uses for const pointer `typedef`s. Everyone who knows C knows the difference between `const int *` and `int *const`. Not everyone automatically sees the difference between `const some_struct` and `const_some_struct`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz pSomeStruct, pcSomeStruct, cpSomeStruct and cpcSomeStruct sound great to me :)

Comment: @user757808 - See, without reading your documentation, I don't know which of `pcSomeStruct` or `cpSomeStruct` is the pointer-to-const-struct. Also, if you're `typedef`ing pointers, why are you using Hungarian notation to let us know that they're pointers? IMHO if you want people to know that an object is a pointer, make them use the `*` in the declaration. If they shouldn't know that it's a pointer, don't ever let them in on this. The C standard library doesn't include a `typedef FILE *pFILE;` despite the fact that all of the file operations operate on opaque pointers.

Comment: @Chris Lutz 1) Having 4 possible is not difficult to get used to 2) I like Hungarian notation. Heck I like CamelCase and snake_tail too

Comment: @user757808 - There's nothing wrong with hungarian notation, but I think type info should be coveyed through the type system - that is, if something is a pointer to a const int, declare it as `const int *`, not `pcInt` or whatever typedef you like. Use hungarian notation for e.g. the distinction between inches and feet, not pointers and qualifiers (because all C programmers know what the first one means, and because one day someone will need to provide a pointer to a `volatile` struct and you won't have provided the appropriate typedef.)

Answer (score 1):

Those are valid, too:

```
typedef struct some_struct {
    int someValue;
} const * pSomeStruct;

typedef struct some_struct {
    int someValue;
} const * const pSomeStruct;
```

This style is not used widely in C++, though. Rather:

```
struct some_struct {
    int someValue;
};

struct some_struct {
    int someValue;
};
```

and then do seperate typedefs. But then, that's not widely used as well. Many other C++ programmers and me would rather declare your functions like `void foo (some_struct const * const)` or similar, apart from the usual reasons against pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding of C type system goes, you should not. First typedef declares type that reas as "pointer to the struct". Applying const to it logically creates "const pointer to the struct". Injecting const'ness to the struct itself would require changing type itself and, so it goes, retypedef'ing.
AFAIK, type composition in C is incremental and you can only make new types by applying modifiers to existing ones, not injecting.

Typedef of a pointer in not a good style anyway.

Comment: Win32 APi is full of such declarations. IMO, it also improves readability if named apropriately.

Comment: Win32 API is not a good style. Actually, one of worst coded major APIs I have ever seen. Readability ( and error-proof'ness ) improves when all pointer operation tell out loud that they are pointer operations.